# Dropped temporary table still exist on the MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, azure, mysql5.7

I am using Azure Database for MySQL server with the MySQL version 5.7 .The issue that I am dealing is that when I am trying to drop a temporary table with these commands :

> DROP TEMPORARY TABLE mdl_backup_ids_temp;

> DROP TABLE mdl_backup_ids_temp;

I got the message that the table is not exist but it seems that the temporary table is still exist when I execute:

> SHOW TABLES;

I already tried to execute:

> FLUSH TABLES;

but without any result. Do have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the command :

> SHOW FULL TABLES;

I don't see anymore the already dropped temporary tables.